# Circular saw drift

Tags: carpentry, circular-saw

This seems to happen on every cut I make, whatever material, width or depth of cut
Clamp down guide piece. No lateral movement.
Start cut flat and straight. The front of the baseplate stays tight to the guide, the rear drifts out maybe up to 1/4 inch, no matter how careful I am

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what else I could add, did you read the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unplug the saw.

Drop the blade all the way down (deepest setting) and pull the guard back, exposing the blade.

Measure from the edge of the baseplate to the front of the blade, and from the edge of the baseplate to the back of the blade. Using a measuring tool with a square included (such as a combination square with a ruler as a blade) is probably the best way to get this measurement consistent. You may want to rotate the blade so that you measure to the same tooth on both ends, since tooth set will affect the measurement.

If those measurements **are not the same**, the saw is not lined up to the baseplate. Either the baseplate attachments can be loosened and corrected, or the baseplate can be filed to match the saw, depending on the saw design.

If those measurements **are the same**, it's probably worth trying a new blade, as your current blade may be damaged in a way that makes it not cut straight.

Comment: A bad saw blade can definitely do this. We bought a new table saw and no matter what we did, we could not get a straight cut. Finally, we replaced the blade that came with the saw and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Question refers to a circular saw (which generally means a portable hand-held, not a tablesaw) so the saw baseplate is the reference to the "fence" (a guide clamped to the work.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply about the baseplate, spot on 